# How to parse HTML content and add inline CSS

Tags: php

I have a HTML editor where the admin can enter their content for a HTML email, but for consistent styles between browsers/clients this needs to include inline css. E.g for a paragraph:

Convert:

```
<p class="standard">
```

Into:

```
<p class="standard" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:18px; color:<?php echo $body_font_color; ?>; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;">
```

I think this is the same as the popular Mail Chimp works by adding inline styles if they dont exist.

Paragraphs are just example, I also have tables and other classes to add styles into.

Comment: I guess I could use simple HTML dom to actually find the different elements using their class name, but how would I go about modifying the inline css

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tools to automatically inline CSS style to create email HTML code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the document into a PHP DOMDocument object. Then you'll have all the methods you need to traverse the DOM tree and make whatever changes you need.

For example:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $para){
  // Get existing style
  if($para->hasAttribute('style')){
    $currStyle = $para->getAttribute('style');
    $para->removeAttribute('style');
  } else {
    $currStyle="";
  }

  // Perform whatever operations on the style you want.

  // comletely replace existing style.
  $para->setAttribute('style','your style string here');
}
$newdoc = $doc->saveHTML();
```

The PHP reference is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 2):

There are tools like [inline styler](https://github.com/davecranwell/inline-styler), which aims to make all CSS inline for e-mails.